# ListBox binding to a Dictionary of class, display the key and select the class object instead of KeyValuePair in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dictionary, data-binding

I have a `ListBox` that I am binding to a `MyDictionary<string, MyClass>` in xaml (`DataContext` is correctly set):

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" 
SelectedIndex="0"
DataContext="{Binding ElementName=thiswindow}"
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMyClass}"
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyDictionary}"
SelectedValuePath="Value"
SelectionChanged="MyListBox_SelectionChanged"
DisplayMemberPath="Key">
```

I am looking to:

1. Display the key, already achieved.
2. Return the selected item of type `MyClass`.

Since `MyDictionary.Value` is of type `MyClass` I did `SelectedValuePath="Value"` but it seems the returned selected object is of type `KeyValuePair<string, MyClass>` according to the error I got:

```
Cannot convert '[Test, MyClass]' from type 'KeyValuePair`2' to type 'MyClass' for 'en-US' culture with default
 conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding.
```

The only solution I found is by using `SelectionChanged` event:

```
private void MyListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var tmp = (KeyValuePair<string, MyClass>)MyListBox.SelectedItem;
            SelectedMyClass= MyDictionary[tmp.Key];    
        }
```

I am sure there is a way to achieve it in xaml only or at least a cleaner way, while keep using the `Dictionary` class.

Maybe with just an additional use of a converter?  what I am missing?

Related question:
[Binding to a class property in a dictionary in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34159046/13085337)

Comment: try `MyListBox.Selectedvalue` instead of MyListBox.SelectedItem, because you configured SelectedValuePath="Value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since there is SelectedValuePath, bind SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem. then it won't be necessary to handle selection event (remove SelectionChanged handler method)

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" 
    SelectedIndex="0"
    DataContext="{Binding ElementName=thiswindow}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedMyClass}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyDictionary}"
    SelectedValuePath="Value"
    DisplayMemberPath="Key">
```